# What does the syntax constant(register) mean?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I'm learning the AT&T syntax for the Intel x86 architecture, and I'm a bit clueless as to the following syntax's meaning:

1. Shrb $1, 2(%esp)
2. Incw 2(%esp)

My initial interpretation was:

1. esp = (esp + 2) >> 1
2. esp = esp + 2

I can't find any reference for using increase in this way, which leads me to believe I'm more fundamentally flawed here.

Is my interpretation correct, or am I completely off-base? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. Just as `(%esp)` refers to the memory location at `%esp` (e.g, treating `%esp` as a pointer), `2(%esp)` refers to the memory location at `%esp + 2`.

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much, I did not realize the paren's did that.